# Which Exception to throw if method is not appropriate for current object

Tags: java, exception

Which Exception do you throw if the method is not appropriate for the current object?

For example in my case I wrote a class called `Interval` which represents a time interval. This class also admits the empty interval (no single point in time is element of this interval). Now I want to implement a method which returns a point in time which is element of this interval. This is of course only possible if the interval is non-empty. So which Exception do I have to throw in case it is empty?

Edit: The Exception I always throw in similar cases is `IllegalArgumentException`. But in this case it doesn't fit since my method gets no argument. It's the object which is in some sense illegal with respect to the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html), [`ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html).

`UnsupportedOperationException` is "part of collections" but both AWT and NIO subclass it.

You can also just make your own special case exception like `EmptyIntervalException extends RuntimeException`. No problem with that if there isn't a perfect fit.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think anyone would find IllegalArgumentException confusing, but you might also try [**IllegalStateException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

In this case it is the Interval that is in an illegal state, i.e. set to an empty time period.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the method throw an [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.

**EDIT:**

As clarified that the method cannot be invoked on the instance itself, then you may either write your own exception, say `EmptyIntervalException`. Or if the `Interval` object can change from state to another (e.g. from empty to non-empty), then [`IllegalStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) would be a good option.

Comment: When I write my own `EmptyIntervalException` which class should be the super class?

Comment: In my class objects of `Interval` can't change. So if an interval is empty once it is empty forever. So they don't change the state. Each time I want to get another interval, a new instance has to be created.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain You can have it extend `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 1):

I would throw an IllegalArgumentException if the argument is not valid.

If it is the state of the object which is invalid you can use `InvalidStateException`.

The best option is to remove the method from this instance if it is not valid to call.  You could have a type/interface where this method is implemented and another where it is not, in which can the compiler will detect you can't call the method.

Another option is to have the method return a `null` or `NoSuchTime` object.  It depends on your expected use case as to which is better.

Comment: My understanding is that the same class represents both empty and non-empty intervals, so you can't remove a method. You probably want to handle empty and non-empty identically most of the time, so again different classes won't work.